# How to restrict the execution of some code for a particular item in getView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, getview, listview-adapter

I have a Async call happening from the getView() in a custom listview adaper, as follows(Last Line):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_posts_item, null);

    holder.tvTitle=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleNamePost);
    holder.ivPrimaryImage=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivPrimaryImage);
    holder.ivPrimaryImage.setId(position);
    holder.ivPrimaryImage.setTag(listOfPosts.get(position).getPostId());
    holder.tvLocality=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocalityPosts);
    holder.tvDateCreated=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateCreated);


    holder.tvTitle.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getTitle());
     holder.ivPrimaryImage.setImageBitmap(listOfPosts.get(position).getImage());

    holder.tvLocality.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getLocality());
    holder.tvDateCreated.setText(listOfPosts.get(position).getCreatedDate());
    postId = listOfPosts.get(position).getPostId();
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setImg(holder.ivPrimaryImage);
    if(!"N".equalsIgnoreCase(listOfPosts.get(position).getHasImage()))
        new GetPrimaryImages().execute(image);
    return rowView;
}
```

The problem is, the Async call is happening everytime the getView is getting executed. Can we restrict the call, only when the item in consideration is an imageView?

Comment: You mean when you "press" a ImageView ?

Comment: @MicheleLacorte No.
As my adapter has 6 rows, I want the following to be executed only 6 times.
 new GetPrimaryImages().execute(image); 

But it is getting executed 6*number of widgets in one row.
I wanted to restrict that.

Comment: iterates on listOfPosts.size(); and set counter has static, I know it is not the best method but it should work

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I did not get you. Can you please support with a piece of code?

Comment: listOfPosts has 6 row right?

Comment: Yes, I tried your soln. But it did not work

Comment: put the piece of code which initializes listOfPost

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be calling async from getView(), as its best to keep this as light as possible and also try to call it as little as possible by proper use of viewholders and recycler views. Im not 100% what way youve done the rest of your code, so here is a good [run through of all the details.](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) There is dozens of other in depth explanations online that will go through all the stuff you need to understand regarding getView() performance.

Answer (score 0):

This helpled:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in my ListView definition. Changing it to fill_parent/match_parent would avoid it.